# Question about continuity in the "complete Skorohod Topology"?

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, stochastic-processes

I am reading the book in progress of Timo Seppäläinen about the "Translation Invariant Exclusion Process"

https://www.math.wisc.edu/~seppalai/excl-book/ajo.pdf

In one of the exercises, exercise 8.9 in page 133, it is asked to prove continuity on $D_{M}$ for the function defined for paths $\alpha \in D_{M}$ as:

$G(\alpha )= \sup_{t \geq 0} e^{-t} d_{M} (\alpha(t), \alpha(t-) ) $

I already have a couple of weeks thinking about it, and even though there is a hint for this exercise I have been unable to solve this. Any recommendation ? My silly approach goes as follows:
Take $\alpha \in D_{M}$ and a sequence $\alpha_{n} \in D_{M}$ such that $s (\alpha_{n}, \alpha ) \rightarrow 0$. Then Assuming that the path $\alpha$ is not continuos:
\begin{align}
& \quad | \sup_{t \geq 0} e^{-t} d_{M} (\alpha(t), \alpha(t-) ) -  \sup_{t \geq 0} e^{-t} d_{M} (\alpha_{n}(t), \alpha_{n}(t-) ) | \\
&= |e^{-T}d_{M} (\alpha(T), \alpha(T-) ) -   e^{-T_{2}} d_{M} (\alpha_{n}(T_{2}), \alpha_{n}(T_{2}-) ) | \\
&\leq |e^{-T}d_{M} (\alpha(T), \alpha(T-) ) -   e^{-T} d_{M} (\alpha_{n}(T), \alpha_{n}(T-) ) | \\
&= e^{-T} |d_{M} (\alpha(T), \alpha(T-) ) -  d_{M} (\alpha_{n}(T), \alpha_{n}(T-) ) | 
\end{align}

I know its lame but I really do not have idea how to proceed. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks in advance